# Add js code to create layout in controller in magento

Tags: magento

I am creating a blocks in my controller using

> $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/mymodule_newpage')

Is there any way how I can embed js code into the addcontent function. I dont want to add complete js but a chunk of code.

Thanks

Comment: Is it a cms static block or module block ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add that particular js file in your static block `(mymodule/mymodule_newpage)` by writing it under `content` tab.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://your_site.com/js/your_js_file.js"></script>
```

Though I am not 100% sure.
Give a try.
Goodluck.

Comment: i created a grid under the file of edit->tab->mypage.php and load that grid using my above code.Now i want to pass some js code with it during creating of layout using $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/mymodule_newpage').how can i do  that , i dont want to pass the whole script file.Hope you got my point

Comment: If I understand correctly. you have a grid and you have a form in which you can edit things. In order to pass scripts to your HTML response, go to your Edit.php and in `__construct()` add a variable `$this->_formScripts[] = 'alert("my code here")'`; This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

$this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/text')->setText('your script here'));

Obs: I could not make sintax highlight fpr PHP work anymore...

Comment: Hi thank for your response i write following code but nothing happend.Code run without error but no alert. $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/adminhtml_mymoduler_edit_tab_myform')->setText("<script>alert('showit');</script>"))